# In terms of ranking, competition, is it idiomatic to say “won THE first place“?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, articles

In terms of ranking, competition, is it idiomatic to say “won/took THE first place“? I have always used and heard it without the definite article.

Comment: Where did you see that? It is possible, but not likely. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a clear-cut idiomatic divide between including the article or not, depending on whether the verb is ***to win*** or ***to take***. As [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20the%20first%20place%2Ctook%20first%20place&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20the%20first%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20first%20place%3B%2Cc0) shows, it was far more common to include it until about a century ago with ***took*** the first place. But per [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=won%20the%20first%20place%2Cwon%20first%20place&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwon%20the%20first%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwon%20first%20place%3B%2Cc0), the usage ***won*** first place wasn't well-established until about then, so it gained traction using the newly-favoured "article-less" form.

Having said that, both versions are at the very least "acceptable" with a broad range of verbs (including ***receive, share, obtain, gain***, etc.) and of possible things won (*second **prize**, [the] **gold** [medal],* etc.).

But *on average*, if you find similar numbers of matches for versions with and without the article, the latter will almost certainly be predominantly *the more recent* instances, so you should copy them.

Comment: I don't think that this usage can be ngrammed. It depends on context. Without context, the difference is meaningless.

Comment: We've been here before. The reason I linked to those charts is because *they confirm to me what I already know*. If you disagree with what I think I know about how English is used (and how it's changed over time, in this specific case), then by all means just say so and make your case. I realise there could be some "false positives" given my specific search strings in those links, but I can assure you I did at least look at some results to satisfy myself they weren't sufficiently numerous as to significantly undermine my point.

Comment: I guess you don't understand what I am saying. I am saying that the usage depends  on context. ***Generally, one would not use a the***. Just saying it's out there does not show actual usage in context. I think one has to show an actual sentence in these cases that shows the **merit** of the determiner.

Comment: Sure, to some extent *usage depends on context*. But the message from my two charts is that one of the more important aspects of that context is *When was the text written?* If the only difference (apart from article presence / absence) between two written examples is that one was written 100 years after the other, it's far more likely the article would be missing from the *later* instance. Which is useful information for learners to be aware of. If you know of some other ***identifiable*** "difference in context" that's significant (and thus *useful*), ***please let everybody know***.

Comment: In my opinion, a high degree of historical information is not helpful to learners. Did I bother learning the pluperfect subjunctive in French so I could say it right off the bat? No. It went "extinct", and if I need it, I look it up. In teaching, I would most likely say: Don't use the "the".